# Selenium use chromium instead of google-chrome in Fedora 35, how can I set google-chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, chromium

firstly with selenium I don't want to use chromium (it takes chromium by default in Linux SO) I'd like to use google-chrome.
Secondly, when I download a file with selenium I'd like to download the file in a specific path for instance : src/resources/downloadFiles/ and it doesen't works, it takes by default /home/myuser/Downloads

This is my code :

protected final static Path DOWNLOAD_PATH = Paths.get("src/resources/downloadFiles/");

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory",System.getProperty(DOWNLOAD_PATH.toString()));
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/home/symlinks/googlechrome/google-chrome");
options.setHeadless(false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I've tried to set ChromeOptions with a new symbolic binary link path of google chrome (either worked with the original binary path of google-chrome) but I got a java.lang.NullPointerException error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
```

(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /home/symlinks/googlechrome/ is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'fedora', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: /home/symlinks/googlechrome/, extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: null}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: /home/symlinks/googlechrome/, extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: null}}}}]

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
at io.rhoar.test.AbstractTest.setUp(AbstractTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:397)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:209)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.rhoar.test.AbstractTest.closeBrowser(AbstractTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:116)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:423)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1082)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:423)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:225)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: I'd advice you to accept and upvote given you answers. This may improve your chances to get an answers.

Comment: I always give an upvote to the given answers, I am not understanding your comment at all

Answer (score -1):

I figured out this is because the version of chrome that I am using in localhost:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94
```

Current browser version is 96.0.4664.110 with binary path /home/symlinks/googlechrome/google-chrome